# How to display any Data from Firestore using ternary operator

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I was trying to fetch data from firebase and I wanted to show an Icon of Instagram only if there is any data available in the firebase collection. I used the following method to fetch the data from firebase

```
StreamBuilder(
        stream: Firestore.instance.collection("aboutpage").snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return Container(
              child: Center(
                child: SpinKitThreeBounce(
                  color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                  size: 30.0,
                ),
              ),
            );
          } else {
            return Container(
              child: ListView.builder(
                physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  DocumentSnapshot aboutpage = snapshot.data.documents[index];
                  return Column(
```

There is no Problem while retrieving data from firebase. Probleme is when I want to display an Instagram icon if the data is available in firebase is used ternary operator but did not work for me

```
"${aboutpage["name"]}" == null 
 ? Container() 
 : IconButton(Icon: Icons.instagram),
   onPressed: (}{}
),
```

I also tried using `"${aboutpage["name"]}".isEmpty` but dint work for me. So, How can I fetch data only if its available and if empty return empty Container?

Answer (score 0):

Change the condition from `"${aboutpage["name"]}" == null` to `aboutpage is Map && aboutpage["name"] == null`.